# Изменить цвет на кнопке

Tags: java, android, xml

Создал простой пустой проект (с пустой активностью), добавил самую обычную кнопку и решил ей поменять цвет. Ниже код, а затем скриншоты с реальной ситуацией:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Цвет, выбранный мною - черный. Что в итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускал на девайсе и на эмуляторе - цвет синий.

Информация:

1. Android Studio 4.1.1
2. Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on
   November 5, 2020
3. Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
4. VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
5. Windows 10 10.0

На эмуляторе API 30, на девайся - 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы попробовал несколько вариантов решения:

1. Установить цвет напрямую в xml а не обращаться к ресурсу
2. Установить цвет программно в активности
3. Добавить в `build.gradle` ([подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678947/how-to-properly-use-backwards-compatible-vector-drawable-with-the-latest-android)):

   ```
   android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
   }
   ...
   }
   ```
4. Попробуйте почистить кэш студии - `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`
5. Засетить фон через drawablу
6. Попробовать убрать  `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"` у кнопки, может там в стилях что-то творится кривое, либо создать свой стиль

Comment: Дело было в стилях, да, и в дизайнере, и в манифесте.

Comment: рад что у вас получилось решить вашу проблему :D